# What are the names in the dead pool in Deadpool?

Tags: marvel, x-men-cinematic-universe, deadpool, deadpool-2016

In the Deadpool movie (2016), there's a betting system called the 'Dead Pool'. What are the names on the board, and are any of them references to the comics or other media?

Comment: Good edit, I was just about to make it clearer regarding the references after reading the first answer

Answer (score 16, accepted):

According to [two](http://comicbook.com/2016/02/20/who-are-the-names-on-deadpools-dead-pool-/) [sources](http://whatculture.com/film/deadpool-12-names-on-the-dead-pool-board-you-probably-missed.php), the names are, or include:

> Shia LaBeouf [Actor]
>
> Bill Cosby [Comedian]
>
> Rob Liefeld [Deadpool creator]
>
> Ryan Reynolds [Deadpool actor]
>
> T.J. Miller [Weasel actor]
>
> Mike Tyson [Boxer]
>
> Ozzy Osbourne [Musician]
>
> Vladimir Putin [Dictator]
>
> Miley Cyrus [Entertainer]
>
> Kanye West [Entertainer]
>
> Lindsay Lohan [Actress]
>
> Charlie Sheen [Actor]

A dead pool is a betting pool in which the wager is on who, among the proffered candidates, will die next. For a non monetary example, see [The Rotten Dead Pool](http://deadpool.rotten.com/).

Comment: I tried to keep the editorializing to a minimum, but I couldn't resist.

Comment: @Politank-Z Clearly, with Lohan listed as an actress.

Comment: @DCShannon Sheen and Miley too. Heck, I think it was mostly junkies or nutheads on that table